# SQL -- Error converting data type numeric to numeric.

Tags: sql

I would appreciate a third eye here. I have a stored procedure to execute but I get the message Error converting data type varchar to numeric when I execute it with the following values

```
            EXECUTE  packaging 
              @ID out,  -- uniqueidentifier
              @ProductID, --uniqueidentifier
              @PackagingIN,  --numeric(14,0)
              @BarCodeInd, --nchar(1)
              @GrossWeightperPack, --numeric(14,0)
              @UMPID,  --uniqueidentifier
              @Height, --numeric(8,0)
              @UMPID1, --uniqueidentifier
              @Width, --numeric(8,0)
              @UMPID2, -- uniqueidentifier
              @Length, --numeric(8,0)
              @UMPID3, --uniqueidentifier
              1,     --int
               1,  --int
              @statusid,  
              @counter out  --int
```

Execute packaging '0904AC11-7B0D-4326-A67B-49639DF6672C', '57925472-5F79-424E-806A-47F8B73DAE02', 57582682639272, '', '', null, '', null, ''null, ''null,'', 1, 1, 'B5266344-286E-46FE-91D1-35DEEDCD6063', @counter

Comment: You are passing the value `''` to the parameter `@GrossWeightperPack` which is defined as `numeric(14,0)`. May be this is the problem.

Comment: @GrossWeightperPack is passed as '' which wont convert to numeric(14,0) ...

Comment: what should I pass it as? Since I am sending the values from the front end, in the case that it is null or empty, what should I send instead?

Comment: `Null` would be a decent start.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few numeric parameters being passed empty strings ''

Pass a numeric value, like you have for the PackagingIN parameter, or pass null

Example:

```
Execute packaging '0904AC11-7B0D-4326-A67B-49639DF6672C', '57925472-5F79-424E-806A-47F8B73DAE02', 57582682639272, '', null, null, null, null, null,null, null,null,null, 1, 1, 'B5266344-286E-46FE-91D1-35DEEDCD6063', @counter
```

Avoid passing empty strings (unless required), as they will trip you up somewhere along the lines

Answer (score 0):

Note that for the question topic: "Error converting data type numeric to numeric." (even though the question body is different), the error can also arise from using a C# `decimal` that does not match the NUMERIC's [precision](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

For instance, passing a `decimal` with value 125.346 as a parameter where the type is `NUMERIC(5,2)` will fail with the above error message.

Answer (score 0):

You may be trying to insert a larger number from the defined template
for example you are running

```
declare **@number numeric (9)**
exec get_next_number @number OUTPUT
```

While the procedure is defined as such

```
procedure dbo.get_next_number **@number numeric(10)**=null OUTPUT
```